# Debian 9 stretch with PHP 7.2: unable to install PDO PHP Extension

Tags: php, debian, pdo

I have installed PHP 7.2 on a Debian 9 server (a docker container actually) and installed some php modules.

But when I get to `gd` and `pdo/mysql` `apt` is unable to find any packages:

```
$apt install php-pdo
Package php-pdo is a virtual package provided by:
   php7.3-common 7.3.0-2 [Not candidate version]
   php7.0-common 7.0.33-0+deb9u1 [Not candidate version]
   php7.0-common 7.0.30-0+deb9u1 [Not candidate version]
```

My sources.list files looks like this:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main
deb https://packages.sury.org/apache2/ stretch main
```

I went through many websites recommending different things, and many of them recommending to add ondrej/php PPAs which I think is only suitable for Ubuntu systems.

PS: the software I'm trying to run over PHP has this requeriment:

- PDO PHP Extension

**Note** I have the same problem with package `php7.2-mysql`

```
$apt-get install php7.2-mysql    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-mysql'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-mysql'
```

**Edit 2**: This is my output of an `apt-get update` (after an `apt-get clean` command to clean the cache):

```
apt-get update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht InRelease
Hit:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht Release
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht/main Sources
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht/main Sources
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht/main Sources
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht/main Sources
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht/main Sources
Err:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian strecht Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/strecht/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such package, as PDO is embedded in the packages providing the SQL modules:

```
Package: php7.2-mysql
Description: MySQL module for PHP
 This package provides the MySQL module(s) for PHP.

Provides: php-mysqli, php-mysqlnd, php-pdo-mysql,
 php7.2-mysqli, php7.2-mysqlnd, php7.2-pdo-mysql

Package: php7.2-pgsql
Description: PostgreSQL module for PHP
 This package provides the PostgreSQL module(s) for PHP.

Provides: php-pdo-pgsql, php-pgsql, php7.2-pdo-pgsql
```

Also notice that these are not packages from Debian 9 Stretch that only [has](https://wiki.debian.org/PHP#How_PHP_is_packaged_in_Debian) PHP 7.0. They are from the [Sury.org](https://deb.sury.org/) repository `deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main` you have added.

Comment: I have the same problem with whits package... I'll edit original post to show it

Comment: And you have `apt-get update`d without errors after adding Sury?

Comment: I get a 404, I'll update OP again to show this. Thank you.

Comment: to add source list use script from:
https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt

Comment: I needed it in Dockerfile, so solved it by:
`FROM php:7.2-apache 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql`

Comment: @mvladk Thanks mate! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Thanks @mvladk !! definitely a lifesaver !!